# Can coins be redeemed for anything besides Basic Packs?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-heroes

After every battle you accumulate some Hero Coins.  Can these coins be used to redeem anything else besides Basic Packs?

[image: Packs]

Comment: No. Just no. (I actually have no idea.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the only pack which can be bought with coins is the Basic Pack.

Once the player has unlocked four copies of each basic card, the coins will be completely removed from the game.

[Source](http://plantsvszombies.wikia.com/wiki/Coin_(PvZH))